# Custom loading icon in primeng datatable

Tags: angular, primeng

In my angular 4 project I have a some primeng datatable and I want to use a custom loading icons when table is loading.
But I don't know how to use a custom icon in the project, I downloaded the icon from [loading.io](https://loading.io/), do I need the css version or svg version?

In Primeng I see that there are this default icon[image]
How can I put mine like this?

Answer (score 2):

Look for the icon you want to display at http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Example : `fa-spinner` is the css class of the following icon http://fontawesome.io/icon/spinner/

In your template, add the loadingIcon propertie :

```
<p-dataTable [value]="values" [loadingIcon]="fa-spinner">
    ...
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: If you only want to change the style, inspect the DOM in order to know how to access to the icon in css. Then add the style in styles.css. For example in your styles.css add : .fa-circle-o-notch{color:red;}

Comment: I want to use a custom icon

Comment: From an image (png) or from a font ?

Comment: I have both css and svg file of my custom icon, is it possible to use it?

Comment: You can try to use a custom css class : [loadingIcon]="customClass" then in the styles.css : .customClass{background-image:"path/to/your/icon";}

Comment: I have used the spinner icon as described. But it is not showing anything